# existe algum debugger que mostre do porque meu código não roda em um determinado browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navegador-de-internet, firefox

usei muito javascript/jquery para montar um projeto, mas acabei testando somente no chrome (está rodando perfeito), dai resolvi testar no firefox e percebi que várias funcionalidades estão travando/não funciona. Existe algum debugger que mostre em que determinada parte não está funcionando ?

Comment: Podes colocar aqui o código? Assim podemos dar uma olhada e ajudar a resolver.

Comment: O próprio console do firefox pode apontar erros e avisos e você também pode fazer teste de perfomance.

Comment: podes um fiddle? e específica melhor que erros acontecem...

Comment: o firefox tem o console nativo ou o http://getfirebug.com/, para IE é possivel utilizar o console

Answer (score 0):

A pergunta é antiga, mas é possível ver quais erros aparecem na página abrindo o *console* na chamada "Ferramentas do desenvolvedor", que é uma ferramenta nativa nos navegadores modernos (em 11/11/2017).

Para abrir o *console*, você pode procurar por algo como "Ferramentas do desenvolvedor" nas abas de opções do navegador ou pressionar tecla(s) de atalho:

- Firefox<sup>1</sup>, Chrome<sup>1</sup>, IE 11<sup>1</sup>, Edge<sup>1</sup>:  <kbd>F12</kbd>
- Opera<sup>1</sup>: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>
- Safari no macOS: <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>

Ao ver quais erros aparecem no *console*, é possível identificar onde está causando erro e o motivo, inclusive identificando a linha do código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desta forma fica mais fácil corrigir o erro, verificando a compatibilidade entre navegadores e fazendo a devida correção.

<sup>1</sup> No Windows 10.